# I put too much oil in my motorcycle, is it going to harm it?

Tags: oil, oil-change

I changed the oil in my 2004 cagiva raptor 125 (transmission) and i put back almost 1 liter of oil. The bike is supposed to have 800ml of oil in it. Is it going to harm it in any way?

Comment: It might differ in a motorcycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overfilling the oil can cause pressure to build up and potentially bust some seals. I would recommend just letting the excess out and stick to the manufacturer recommended volume.

If you really want, save a 1/5th of each liter, and every fifth oil change will be free :)

Comment: Makes sense. I'm going to drain out the excess oil tomorrow.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how a high oil level can cause increased oil pressure in a traditional engine with an oil pump?

Comment: Too much oil can potentially cause some of the oil to burn (Crankcase breather >> air cleaner box >> induction sys). Burning oil can lead to a slew of problems incl broken seals, burnt valves, and fouled plugs. Maybe 200mL isn't enough to cause any problems, but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: Here's an article with some more explanation on the topic: http://www.cycleworld.com/2013/08/09/ask-kevin-can-adding-too-much-oil-lead-to-engine-damage

Comment: If the extra oil is enough to hitthe crankwebs then it gets severly frothed up and blows the seals and other things ... but if you haven't seen it you won't believe...

Comment: Slight overfilling is generally not a serious problem, but if you have too much oil and the crank dips into the pool of oil in the pan, it can foam up and lose its effectiveness as a lubricant, damaging the engine. If you have way, way too much oil, then it will impede the engine's rotation, blow out seals, possibly hydrolock the engine, etc. I would also recommend draining the excess as you're about 25% overfilled, unless you specifically know about your model that there's enough room for the extra oil and it won't cause the aforementioned issues.